# Delete messages JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Im using JSQMessagesViewController to implement chat to my app.
How can I delete messages?

I found this method to handle deletion:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didDeleteMessageAt indexPath: IndexPath!) {

}
```

But I don't know how to delete message at index path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are saving the messages l. In my own implementation I have an array of messages `var messages = [JSQMessage]`
So since you have that delete method you know which message needs to be removed so you should be able to call something along these lines 
`messages.remove(at: indexPath.item)`
Now if you are using some type of backed this is where you would call the appropriate method from your API. You will most likely want to call `collectionView.reloadData()` after it completes.

Hope that this helps

if not could you share the code your are struggling with

Comment: How to show menu for deleting message bubble in Swift 3 ?

Comment: That question is a little ambiguous. You need context of which message it is. You could use the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath()` method and show a menu based off of that items location on the screen but I don't know if that is what you are looking for.